Zigzag/Snake-identities in monoidal categories
This is a rather elementary question; I have not put much time into understanding string diagrams, and still find them quite confusing to interpret. If $(Y,\text{ev},\text{coev})$ is the duality data for some object $X \in (\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ where $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is monoidal, what are the zigzag-equations in equational form?
(I could only find string-diagrammatic representations of the identities).
Am I correct that it is $$X \simeq \mathbf{1} \otimes X \overset{\text{coev} \otimes \text{id}}{\to} (X \otimes Y) \otimes X \simeq X \otimes (Y \otimes X) \overset{\text{id} \otimes \text{ev}}{\to} X \otimes \mathbf{1} \simeq X$$ and that this is equal to $\text{id}_{X}$, and similarly for $Y$?

Yes, that's right.
